# Python numpy 3D array to 2D array (removing dimensions)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a numpy array `Z` such that:

```
Z.shape

#Out[1]:
    (138, 112, 123)
```

How do I transform `Z` into a new array `NewZ`, such that:

```
NewZ.shape

#Out[2]:
    (138, 112)
```

?

Comment: What operation do you want performed on the dimension you want removed?  `NewZ = np.max(Z, axis=2)` would yield a `NewZ.shape` of `(138, 112)`, for example.

Comment: An array of shape `(138, 112, 123)` has `1901088` elements.  An array of shape `(138, 112)` has only `15456` elements.  So which `15456` elements of the original array do you want to end up in the new array?

Comment: @DolphinGenomePyramids: Can you edit the question to clarify what sort of reduction operation you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Removing a dimension means removing information, so you'll have to decide on a rule for projecting the original data down into a lower number of dimensions.

Suppose we have

```
import numpy as np
Z = np.random.random((138, 112, 123))
```

Here are two examples, both yielding a `NewZ.shape` of `(138, 112)`:

- `NewZ = np.max(Z, axis=2)`, which takes the largest element of the last axis.
- `NewZ = Z[:,:,0]`, which takes the first element of the last axis.